# Python Tornado: nested templating

Tags: templates, tornado

Is it possible to do some sort of `eval` in tornado templates?

Let me show an example of what I wish to do:

```
{% for c in columns %}
    <!-- cdata is a dictionary, and columns is a list -->
    <div class="cell"> {{ cdata[ {{ c }} ] }} </div>
{% end %}
```

e.g. I want to evaluate the current value in `columns`, and use it as a key to search in the `cdata` dictionary.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions in Tornado templates cannot be nested, but they're just python expressions, which gives you the flexibility to do what you want. This includes calling the python `eval` if that's what you need, but it looks like in this case you simply need `{{ cdata[c] }}`.